# Slowly updating dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Current and new data
[image: Current data and new data]

Expected outcome
[image: Expected outcome]
Current code:

```
update product_dim
set [expiry_date] = getdate() -1
from product_stg a, product_dim b
where a.product_code = b.product_code
and ( a.product_name = b.product_name
    or a.product_price = b.product_price
    or a.product_category = b.product_category
)
and [expiry_date] = '9999-12-31'
```

I've got barely an idea of what to do here. I could just be being dumb, but I've gotta get this assignment in in two days, and have more to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? What is the datatype of `expiry_date` column(I think you're storing dates as strings which is bad)?. Get ride of the old ANSI-89 JOIN syntax.

Comment: I'm trying to insert the "new" products to the table, and expire the old ones without removing them, since stuff like the price is different. The expiry_date column uses the date datatype.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. I was just being dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I didn't insert the new data after updating the expiry_date field. My brain needs a rework lol.